# Game will not reset after win/loss conditions are met

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making an onclick game that randomly generates a number to reach and randomly generates a number for each object to click. I am able to get everything working but cannot get the game to reset.

I've tried multiple different functions and moving them and nesting them. I am new so i feel like my functions are weak and need more work.

```
function startgame(){

  let randomNumer = 50 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
  console.log(randomNumer);

  let crystalOne = 5 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
  console.log(crystalOne);

  let crystalTwo = 8 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);
  console.log(crystalTwo);

  let crystalThree = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 22);
  console.log(crystalThree);

  let crystalFour = 20 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
  console.log(crystalFour);

  let wins = 0;
  let losses = 0;
  let score = 0;
  let counter = 0;



  $(".randomnumber").text(randomNumer);


  $("#crystalone").on("click", function () {
    counter + crystalOne;
    $(".score").text(counter += crystalOne);
    $("#firstcrystal").text(crystalOne);
    checker();
  });
  $("#crystaltwo").on("click", function () {
    counter + crystalTwo;
    $(".score").text(counter += crystalTwo);
    $("#secondcrystal").text(crystalTwo);
    checker();
  });
  $("#crystalthree").on("click", function () {
    counter + crystalThree;
    $(".score").text(counter += crystalThree);
    $("#thirdcrystal").text(crystalThree);
    checker();
  });
  $("#crystalfour").on("click", function () {
    counter + crystalFour;
    $(".score").text(counter += crystalFour);
    $("#fourthcrystal").text(crystalFour);
    checker();
  });
  function checker() {

    if (counter > randomNumer) {
        losses++;
        $("#losses").append(losses);
        reset();
        // startgame();
    }


    if (counter === randomNumer) {
        wins++;
        $("#wins").append(wins);
        reset();
        // startgame();
    }

  };

};


startgame();


function reset() {

    let randomNumer = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
    console.log(randomNumer);

    let crystalOne = 5 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
    console.log(crystalOne);

    let crystalTwo = 8 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);
    console.log(crystalTwo);

    let crystalThree = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 22);
    console.log(crystalThree);

    let crystalFour = 20 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
    console.log(crystalFour);


    $(".randomnumber").on("click").text(randomNumer);
    startgame();

};
```

game works and records wins and losses but doesn't reset.

Comment: Hi Skinnymedic, welcome to StackOverflow! Could you post the code in your `reset` function that you are having trouble with?

Comment: Yes is can. I thought it was in there, sorry.

Comment: i fixed the original post to include the reset

Answer (score 1):

the variables in `reset` don't do anything, since they are local to reset function and not visible in `startgame`

also, `randomNumer` is not visible in `reset`.

add to `startgame`:

```
$(".score").text('0');
```

also, you can drop the reset function completely, since it doesn't do anything useful except calling the startgame, and instead call startgame in checker where before you'd call reset.